# How to print receipt without print dialog box in client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, printing, epson

I want print receipt in client side without print dialog box, i am using mvc this is my solution to achieve my problem.
EPSON printer was installed in my system.This solution is working when host in my local iis but its not work when host in server and accessing from my local system getting "An error occurred while processing your request" error. In server no printer is installed.

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: '../Service/print',
cache: false,
data: { iprintData: printData, iprinterName: sPrinterName },
success: function (data) {
// alert('print Send Successfully');
},
error: function (ex) {
   alert(ex.responseText);
// alert('error while Seding print');
}
});
```

this is my code in controller

> ```
>     public JsonResult print(string iprintData, string iprinterName)
>     {
>         Boolean bflag = false;
>         System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["_printData"] = iprintData; 
>         PrintDocument printDocument = new PrintDocument();
>         printDocument.PrintController = new StandardPrintController();            
>         printDocument.PrintPage += PrintDocumentOnPrintPage;
>         printDocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = iprinterName;
>         //printFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 10);
>         printDocument.Print();
>         bflag = true;            
>         return Json(bflag, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
>     }
>
>     public static Image resizeImage(Image image, int new_height, int new_width)
>     {
>         Bitmap new_image = new Bitmap(new_height, new_width);
>         Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((Image)new_image);
>         g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.High;
>         g.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, new_width, new_height);
>         return new_image;
>     }
>     private void PrintDocumentOnPrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
>     {
>         string printstring = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["_printData"].ToString();
>         string path = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/content/Images/logo.png");
>         System.Drawing.Image img = Image.FromFile(path);
>
>
>         //img = resizeImage(img, 80, 60);
>         e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, 6, 100);
>         e.Graphics.DrawString(printstring, new System.Drawing.Font("ronnia", 9), Brushes.Black, 10, 150);
>     }
> ```

can any one help me from this ?

Answer (score 1):

1. first you have to write windows service that contain HttpListener.
2. write your printing code inside the service
3. Install the service in client machine
4. call that service using ajax like below.

```js
    function PrintReceipt() {

        var PrintData = JSON.parse($("#receiptData").html())

        if (PrintData.length > 0) {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST", 
                url: "http://localhost:41963/printOrder",
                data: JSON.stringify({ "PrintData": PrintData }), //reciept data
                crossDomain: true, 
                success: function (response) {

                    
                },
                error: function () {
                  
                }
            });
        }

       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

set System.Drawing.dll property

```
Copy Local=true
```

Comment: system.Drawing.dll is in bin.

Comment: click on references then right click on System.Drawing take properties

Comment: Drawing.dll has same properties and it was shipped with bin folder after published web site.